# google-api-php-client photo gallery not working

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, google-api-php-client, google-photos-api

I have integrated google-api-php-client using composer in my Codeigniter PHP application.
Google_Client is created successfully, and able to fetch sample api for Google Books. PhotoGallery service not working.

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('/path/to/json/my_credentials.json');
$client->setAccessType('offline');

$service = new Google_Service_PhotosLibrary($client);
```

The service object return below value:

```
{
 albums: { },
 mediaItems: { },
 sharedAlbums: { },
 batchPath: null,
 rootUrl: "https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/",
 version: "v1",
 servicePath: "",
 availableScopes: null,
 resource: null,
 serviceName: "photoslibrary"
}
```

How to list albums using this service, and then also list the photos inside it.

Comment: Have you checked API documentation? See here https://google.github.io/php-photoslibrary/v1.1.0/classes/Google.Photos.Library.V1.ListAlbumsRequest.html

Comment: @Labradorcode: let me check and try it

Answer (score 0):

`setAuthConfig()` should receive a JSON:

```
$auth_data = json_decode(file_get_contents(AUTH_FILE), TRUE);
$client->setAuthConfig($auth_data);
```